# Delphi Using Indy 10

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-4, indy-9

I'm using Delphi 4, and I want to create a standard non blocking socket with out the clutter of Indy code (Pv4 and Pv6). and i want to get the computers IP address and be able to ping has any one done this. Can I do it with Indy 10 or Indy 9. And has any one made code up to do any of these things and tested it please.

Answer (score 8):

Indy officially stopped supporting Delphi 4 a long time ago.  Delphi 5 is the earliest version still supported.  Delphi has its own socket classes - TClientSocket and TServerSocket - which can operate in both blocking and non-blocking modes.  Indy operates strictly in blocking mode only.

Without using Indy, you can get the machine's IP(s) using either the WinSock API's [gethostname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738527.aspx) and [gethostbyname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524.aspx) functions, or the Win32 API's [GetAdapterAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915.aspx) or related functions, and use the Win32 API [IcmpSendEcho](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366050.aspx) function to ping.